# How to show progress bar on the go without any activity?

Tags: android, progress-bar

My XML:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />
```

Right now I am showing a progress bar in an activity.

In my first activity, I am showing a listview. On clicking any item in the list view it starts downloading the data using the download manager. For example, If a file is PDF then after download it will ask How do you want to open this?
So during the download process, I want to show my progress bar in the first activity. Right now after the download is over it opens the file but on pressing the back button it is showing the progress bar activity.

Comment: Please show how you are handling the download start/finish.

Comment: I resolve it  thanks @Nfear by adding 
                finish();

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by handling the back button programmatically....

```
    @Override public void onBackPressed() { // your code. }
```

Add this function to your activity and handle the back button so as to not allow it to go back...